# Is it possible to use something like "--cache-from" in docker-compose?

Tags: docker-compose

Is it possible to use something like "--cache-from" in docker-compose?
My CI pipeline uses dynamically provided EC2 instances. During EC2 boot it's downloading updated Docker images, and I'd like to use them as cache for 'docker-compose build'. I know that 'docker build' supports '--cache-from', but what  about docker-compose?